# Maintaining previous position of player in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a board where two-player move cell by cell in turn. I want to maintain their previous cell position as well. 
Here are the most relevant code snippets.

Arrow Keys Event listener

```
// Event listener for the arrow keys
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case arrowKeysCode.left:
      if (playerTurn === 1) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player1.indexPosition.row][player1.indexPosition.col - 1] &&
          player1.indexPosition.col > 0
        ) {
          playerTurn = 2;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);
          moveLeft(player1);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 1;
        }
      } else if (playerTurn === 2) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player2.indexPosition.row][player2.indexPosition.col - 1] &&
          player2.indexPosition.col > 0
        ) {
          playerTurn = 1;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);

          moveLeft(player2);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 2;
        }
      }
      break;
    case arrowKeysCode.up:
      if (playerTurn === 1) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player1.indexPosition.row - 1][player1.indexPosition.col] &&
          player1.indexPosition.row > 0
        ) {
          playerTurn = 2;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);

          moveUp(player1);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 1;
        }
      } else if (playerTurn === 2) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player2.indexPosition.row - 1][player2.indexPosition.col] &&
          player2.indexPosition.row > 0
        ) {
          playerTurn = 1;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);

          moveUp(player2);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 2;
        }
      }
      break;
    case arrowKeysCode.right:
      if (playerTurn === 1) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player1.indexPosition.row][player1.indexPosition.col + 1] &&
          player1.indexPosition.col <
            mapArray[player1.indexPosition.row].length - 1
        ) {
          playerTurn = 2;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);

          moveRight(player1);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 1;
        }
      } else if (playerTurn === 2) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player2.indexPosition.row][player2.indexPosition.col + 1] &&
          player2.indexPosition.col <
            mapArray[player2.indexPosition.row].length - 1
        ) {
          playerTurn = 1;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);

          moveRight(player2);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 2;
        }
      }
      break;
    case arrowKeysCode.down:
      if (playerTurn === 1) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player1.indexPosition.row + 1][player1.indexPosition.col] &&
          player1.indexPosition.row < mapArray.length - 1
        ) {
          playerTurn = 2;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);

          moveDown(player1);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 1;
        }
      } else if (playerTurn === 2) {
        if (
          !mapArray[player2.indexPosition.row + 1][player2.indexPosition.col] &&
          player2.indexPosition.row < mapArray.length - 1
        ) {
          playerTurn = 1;
          updateTurn(playerTurn);

          moveDown(player2);
        } else {
          playerTurn = 2;
        }
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

Movement Functions

```
const moveRight = player => {
  {
    clearCell(player);
    maintainPreviousPosition(player);

    player.position.x += offset;
    player.indexPosition.col += 1;
    console.log(player);

    if (areClose(player1, player2)) {
      startFight(player1, player2, playerTurn);
    }

    let weaponIndex = chkWeapon(player);
    if (weaponIndex > -1) {
      updateWeapon(weaponIndex, player);
      drawPlayer(player);
    } else {
      drawPlayer(player);
    }
  }
};
const moveDown = player => {
  {
    clearCell(player);
    maintainPreviousPosition(player);

    player.position.y += offset;
    player.indexPosition.row += 1;
    console.log(player);
    if (areClose(player1, player2)) {
      startFight(player1, player2, playerTurn);
    }

    let weaponIndex = chkWeapon(player);
    if (weaponIndex > -1) {
      updateWeapon(weaponIndex, player);
      drawPlayer(player);
    } else {
      drawPlayer(player);
    }
  }
};
```

Maintain previous position function.

```
const maintainPreviousPosition = player => {
  console.log(player);
  if (player.id === 1) {
    p1PreviousPosition.canvasPosition = player.position;
    p1PreviousPosition.indexPosition = player.indexPosition;
  } else if (player.id === 2) {
    p2PreviousPosition.canvasPosition = player.position;
    p2PreviousPosition.indexPosition = player.indexPosition;
  }
};
```

But the problem is when I console previousPosition and currentPosition of player, it remain the same. 
You can checkout github repo of the project.
https://hassanraja447.github.io/offensive-strike/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`player.position` and `player.indexPosition` are objects. Because of this, they're copied by reference, not by value. (You're not getting a second object, you're just getting another reference to the first object.)

You probably want something like this instead:

```
p1PreviousPosition.canvasPosition = {
    x: player.position.x,
    y: player.position.y
};
```

or some other means of deep copy.

Comment: Yeah, player is a class. I will check in a moment.